# Is there a way to do uart_recieve without using "while" on stm32?

Tags: stm32, uart

I want to receive data using UART_Receive.
However, if UART_Receive is not included in the while statement, the data will not be received properly.

I don't want to impose restrictions on executing certain events and other code when uart occurs.

Is there any way to get the data when uart occurs at any time?

I am currently using UART_RECEIVE_DMA.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "I don't want to impose restrictions on executing certain events"? But there is a way to receive data at any time and it's through [interrupts](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/embedded_systems/es_interrupts.htm) that you can accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use UART idle interrupt

```
void My_UART_IRQHandler(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_IDLE))
    {
        __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IDLEFLAG(huart);
        // data is stored in uartData
    }
}
    
void InitUART(void)
{
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart, UART_IT_IDLE);
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart, uartData, size);
}
```

Go to USARTx_IRQHandler in stm32xxxx_it.c and add call My_UART_IRQHandler:

```
   void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
   {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 0 */
    
    /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 0 */
       HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 1 */
       My_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
    /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 1 */
   }
```

Don't forget to enable UART interrupts and use DMA for UART TX

Answer (score 0):

In three ways UARTdata can be received.

- polling
- Interrupt
- DMA

DMA or interrupt UART receive methods can be triggered anytime when the UART signal occurs. So using UART_RECEIVE_DMA and "imposing restrictions on executing certain events and other code when uart occurs" is kind of strange to me.

In the DMA method, you do not need to call the UART to receive on the while() loop. For learning and receiving fixed-length data can try this [resource](https://deepbluembedded.com/how-to-receive-uart-serial-data-with-stm32-dma-interrupt-polling/).

If the data length is unknown can use IDLE line detection. Use this [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bo6MC5A8uTE&t=1031s) from controllers tech for more details.

Answer (score 0):

One way is an interrupt-based circular FIFO queue.

Issue a recieve-call for a byte (or more), when the interrupt service routine is called, stuff the byte/s in the FIFO and then process the data in-between.

This allows for data reception to be done quickly, so you can do the other things that seem to be a worry.

If you're worried about servicing the other peipherals, you may want to go with a pre-emptive approach with either a Real-time Operating System, or priority-based interrupts.  This will give you control over when exactly things are serviced.